# Searching one collection multiple times in one call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an array with multiple values which need to be used as queries to search a collection. I am not sure of a way of doing this using one route. for example:

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
let ArrayOfIds = [id1, id2, id3]

Movie.find({user: req.user.id}).then(items => {
//Something along this lines 
 items.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
 Movie.find({user: subscription})
  //This wont work beacuse of the callback promise
   .then(movies => {
    items.push(movies)
 })
 })
res.render('index/home',
 {pageName: 'Movies', items: items})
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
})
```

I want to search the same collection (Movie) for each id and add it to the items object. Doing it with a for loop seems to create a set header error. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your model

Answer (score 0):

This S/O response should have your answer...

[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

From the response:

> The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that
>   you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried
>   to set a header or statusCode. When you see this error, try to look
>   for anything that tries to send a header after some of the body has
>   already been written. For example, look for callbacks that are
>   accidentally called twice, or any error that happens after the body is
>   sent.
>
> In your case, you called res.redirect(), which caused the response to
>   become Finished. Then your code threw an error (res.req is null). and
>   since the error happened within your actual function(req, res, next)
>   (not within a callback), Connect was able to catch it and then tried
>   to send a 500 error page. But since the headers were already sent,
>   Node.js's setHeader threw the error that you saw.

It's likely that you're calling res.redirect() multiple times if you're implementing a for-loop.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm trying to avoid doing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if I understand correctly, you can query the collection with list of ids in your case ArrayOfIds into in query of mongo.
Check [$in query of mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).
FYI: create some index on that field.